# Restore internet connectivity without Raspberry Pi reboot

Tags: wifi, modules, services

Occasionally, my Raspberry Pi 4 disconnects from internet. This unwanted disconnection seems to be due to some errors from wi-fi module drivers. Here is an excerpt of the kernel log:

```
ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_fw_crashed: Firmware has halted or crashed
ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_fil_cmd_data: bus is down. we have nothing to do.
ieee80211 phy0: brcmf_cfg80211_get_tx_power: error (-5)
brcmfmac: brcmf_sdiod_probe: Failed to set F1 blocksize
brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_bus_reset: Failed to probe after sdio device reset: ret -123
mmc1: card 0001 removed
mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0xc1 (4 bytes)
mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x04 (0 bytes)
mmc1: bad CIS tuple 0x20 (0 bytes)
mmc1: error -22 whilst initialising SDIO card
```

I was wondering which operations should be done in the machine in order to restore connectivity with internet without completely rebooting the Raspberry Pi. I tried to reload some kernel module, as [here](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=248156) explained, restart services like `networking` and `dhcpcd` but all these actions didn't actually make the device connect back to the wi-fi network (`wlan0` was still no listed from `ifconfig -a`).

Comment: Are you running the latest Bullseye fully updated?

Comment: @CoderMike, well, I cannot check this right now but as far as I remember, no: I installed Buster.

Comment: I would suggest flashing the latest Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye. https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/

Comment: @CoderMike, the Raspberry Pi is currently located inside a kind of smart clock and so I can't physically interface with it. I can only SSH to it and, as far as I remember, upgrading the OS via `apt-get dist-upgrade` is discouraged, isn't it?

Comment: Thats a bad design if you can't get to the sd card. Yes, upgrading Buster to Bullseye is discouraged. A fresh install is always recommended.

Comment: You can't resolve `brcmf_fw_crashed` without a reboot (ideally a power cycle). Upgrade to RaspiOS Bullseye January 28th 2022 version to get a fully up to date system with latest stable kernel and latest BRCM firmware.